# What is the preferred way to preallocate NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to NumPy/SciPy. From the documentation, it seems more efficient to preallocate
a single array rather than call append/insert/concatenate.

For example, to add a column of 1's to an array, i think that this:

```
ar0 = np.linspace(10, 20, 16).reshape(4, 4)
ar0[:,-1] = np.ones_like(ar0[:,0])
```

is preferred to this:

```
ar0 = np.linspace(10, 20, 12).reshape(4, 3)
ar0 = np.insert(ar0, ar0.shape[1], np.ones_like(ar0[:,0]), axis=1)
```

my first question is whether this is correct (that the first is better), and my second question is, at the moment, I am just preallocating my arrays like this (which I noticed in several of the Cookbook examples on the SciPy Site):

```
np.zeros((8,5))
```

what is the 'NumPy-preferred' way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Preallocation mallocs all the memory you need in one call, while resizing the array (through calls to append,insert,concatenate or resize) may require copying the array to a larger block of memory. So you are correct, preallocation is preferred over (and should be faster than) resizing.

There are a number of "preferred" ways to preallocate numpy arrays depending on what you want to create. There is `np.zeros`, `np.ones`, `np.empty`, `np.zeros_like`, `np.ones_like`, and `np.empty_like`, and many others that create useful arrays such as `np.linspace`, and `np.arange`.

So

```
ar0 = np.linspace(10, 20, 16).reshape(4, 4)
```

is just fine if this comes closest to the `ar0` you desire.

However, to make the last column all 1's, I think the preferred way would be to just say

```
ar0[:,-1]=1
```

Since the shape of `ar0[:,-1]` is `(4,)`, the 1 is [broadcasted](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) to match this shape.

Comment: What about datetime array? None of the once you suggest above seem to work. Nor does something like `my_array= numpy.empty(10, dtype=numpy.datetime64)`. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In cases where performance is important, **`np.empty`** and **`np.zeros`** appear to be the fastest ways to initialize numpy arrays.

Below are test results for each method and a few others. Values are in seconds.

```
>>> timeit("np.empty(1000000)",number=1000, globals=globals())
0.033749611208094166
```

```
>>> timeit("np.zeros(1000000)",number=1000, globals=globals())
0.03421245135849915
```

```
>>> timeit("np.arange(0,1000000,1)",number=1000, globals=globals())
1.2212416112155324
```

```
>>> timeit("np.ones(1000000)",number=1000, globals=globals())
2.2877375495381145
```

```
>>> timeit("np.linspace(0,1000000,1000000)",number=1000, globals=globals())
3.0824269766860652
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `numpy.empty()` is the fastest way to preallocate HUGE arrays. The arrays that I'm talking about have shapes similar to `(80,80,300000)` and a dtype `uint8`.

Here is the code:

```
%timeit  np.empty((80,80,300000),dtype='uint8')
%timeit  np.zeros((80,80,300000),dtype='uint8')
%timeit  np.ones((80,80,300000),dtype='uint8')
```

and results from timing:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.7 µs per loop  # Much faster
1 loop, best of 3: 273 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 272 ms per loop
```