# Merging a list of numpy arrays into one array (fast)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

what would be the fastest way to merge a list of numpy arrays into one array if one knows the length of the list and the size of the arrays, which is the same for all?

I tried two approaches:

- `merged_array = array(list_of_arrays)` from [Pythonic way to create a numpy array from a list of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106287/pythonic-way-to-create-a-numpy-array-from-a-list-of-numpy-arrays) and
- `vstack`

A you can see `vstack` is faster, but for some reason the first run takes three times longer than the second. I assume this caused by (missing) [preallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491802/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-preallocate-numpy-arrays). So how would I preallocate an array for `vstack`? Or do you know a faster methode?

Thanks!

**[UPDATE]**

**I want `(25280, 320)` not `(80, 320, 320)`** which means, `merged_array = array(list_of_arrays)` wont work for me. Thanks Joris for pointing that out!!!

**Output:**

```
0.547468900681 s merged_array = array(first_list_of_arrays)
0.547191858292 s merged_array = array(second_list_of_arrays)
0.656183958054 s vstack first
0.236850976944 s vstack second
```

**Code:**

```
import numpy
import time
width = 320
height = 320
n_matrices=80

secondmatrices = list()
for i in range(n_matrices):
    temp = numpy.random.rand(height, width).astype(numpy.float32)
    secondmatrices.append(numpy.round(temp*9))

firstmatrices = list()
for i in range(n_matrices):
    temp = numpy.random.rand(height, width).astype(numpy.float32)
    firstmatrices.append(numpy.round(temp*9))


t1 = time.time()
first1=numpy.array(firstmatrices)
print time.time() - t1, "s merged_array = array(first_list_of_arrays)"

t1 = time.time()
second1=numpy.array(secondmatrices)
print time.time() - t1, "s merged_array = array(second_list_of_arrays)"

t1 = time.time()
first2 = firstmatrices.pop()
for i in range(len(firstmatrices)):
    first2 = numpy.vstack((firstmatrices.pop(),first2))
print time.time() - t1, "s vstack first"

t1 = time.time()
second2 = secondmatrices.pop()
for i in range(len(secondmatrices)):
    second2 = numpy.vstack((secondmatrices.pop(),second2))

print time.time() - t1, "s vstack second"
```

Comment: Use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to do simple performance testing in Python. It produce more accurate results.

Comment: What dimensions you want the merged array to have? Because ``first1`` is ``(80, 320, 320)`` and ``first2`` is ``(25280, 320)``

Comment: @joris, thanks for pointing that out. I want the second one, which was my initial approach. I will change it in the question.

Comment: Then you need ``vstack`` instead of ``dstack`` from eumiro's answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have 80 arrays 320x320? So you probably want to use `dstack`:

```
first3 = numpy.dstack(firstmatrices)
```

This returns one 80x320x320 array just like `numpy.array(firstmatrices)` does:

```
timeit numpy.dstack(firstmatrices)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.1 ms per loop


timeit numpy.array(firstmatrices)
1 loops, best of 3: 750 ms per loop
```

If you want to use `vstack`, it will return a 25600x320 array:

```
timeit numpy.vstack(firstmatrices)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi eurmiro, sorry my question was unclear. I actually need (25280, 320) and not (80, 320, 320). See update of my question.